# How can I programmatically update the settings of a View display?

Tags: 8, views, configuration

I can load a ViewExecutable and create a new Display programmatically:

```
$view = Views::getView('existing_view');
$display = $view->newDisplay('page', 'New page', 'page_2');
```

But how can I update the settings for the new display programmatically?

The display is an instance of [\Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21display%21Page.php/class/Page/8.4.x) but I can't see any way of saving options to it.

The [setOption](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21display%21DisplayPluginBase.php/function/DisplayPluginBase%3A%3AsetOption/8.4.x) method exists, but how can persist the options to storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:
The settings are not made on the display, but on the *handler*.

```
$view = Views::getView('existing_view');
$display = $view->newDisplay('page', 'New page', 'page_2');

// ViewExecutable::setHandlerOption($display_id, $type, $id, $option, $value)
$view->setHandlerOption('page_2', 'argument', 'nid', 'admin_label', 'Foo');
$view->save();
```

Options and values correspond to the values in a View YAML config file, under `display_options`.

Important is that you find out the correct `$type` argument.

I had a look at the array keys returned from [ViewExecutable::getHandlers](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/function/ViewExecutable%3A%3AgetHandlers/8.4.x).

- "field"
- "argument"
- "sort"
- "filter"
- "relationship"
- "header"
- "footer"
- "empty"

Comment: Yes, but most times it's easier to update the settings in `$view->storage` directly (this is the config entity of the view), see for example https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21Menu%21ViewsMenuLink.php/function/ViewsMenuLink%3A%3AupdateLink/8.5.x

Comment: Was just looking at that: it's the only way to update the path, AFAICS. The interface seems a bit lacking – there's no "setter" method. You get the array by reference, change it, and call `save`.

Comment: Having the display settings in an array is IMHO much easier, and the example shows that even the Views module is using this method.

Comment: Not saying it doesn't work. Accessing a public property to update an entity just feels unusual.

Comment: Good point, but in Views there are a lot of things not fully object-oriented yet.